# Time Complexity in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, time-complexity

Let's assume that we have two tables:

A - contains id, name

B - contains id, school

Is there any time complexity difference between

```
Select A.name from A inner join B on A.id=B.id and B.school='Harvard'

Select name from A where id=(select id from B where school='Harvard')
```

I usually go by the first code, but I was wondering if the second code is more efficient time-wise.

Comment: Check execution plans for both (I guess they should be the similiar), but first approach is more readable

Comment: I prefer , Select A.name from A inner join B on A.id=B.id where  B.school='Harvard'

Comment: There's nothing here that you couldn't test for yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on many things from amount of data, indexes to possibly even hardware configuration. You should really check the execution plan to verify this, but in my experience shouldn't be a big difference in performance in most cases.

But there is a functional difference. If, say, a subject would have been to Harvard twice (having two records in B), the second query would still return that subject once, while the first query will return him twice.

And even if that would be covered by having a unique constraint of any kind on ID or ID/School, there is still the semantic difference. The construct with `in` suggests you only want persons/names that meet certain criteria, while the version with `join` suggests you may want to return the actual data about the school. The intention is less clear in the `join` version, which may lead to bugs being introduced in later modification of this code.